# Ubuntu 16 LTS and Asus Xonar DS don't work sound

Tags: sound, asus

I have sound card the Asus Xonar DS and i installed Ubuntu 16 LTS but sound doesn't works.
I checked utility alsamixer and pavucontrol sound is on and don't mute.
I watch my sound card in alsamixer and pavucontrol
How to fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. This is a bug of the driver. It can be solved by disconnecting cable of front panel from soundcard. Or, you need to insert the headphones in the front panel input.